# PHP execute a python in shell, do not wait for executing but will get the result

Tags: php, python, shell, bluetooth, raspberry-pi

I have been looking around for an answer, but all the questions are directing to that the PHP script do not wait output, also do not get the output back...

What I am working on is a simple php webpage, which execute a python script to inquire nearby bluetooth devices and display the result. The bluetooth inquiring python do takes up some time to run, therefore when I execute the python script from PHP, the whole webpage waits for a output from shell and hangs.

Is there a possibility to display all the rest of the page first - header, footer, etc., and then pop the shell result back into the webpage somehow? Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running the script inside an Iframe or by an Ajax request.

```
<html>
    <header>
       <title>...</title>
    </header>
   <body>
      <header>...</header>
      <iframe src="bluetoothscript.php"></iframe>
      <footer>...</footer>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, my friend also suggested to use Ajax. I just try it and it works. :)